# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 wifi adaptor not recognized in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

Wifi section in settings show no wifi adapter found, but output below shows the physical adapter present:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Somewhere along the way on the many forums I've read through I found the following command:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for josh: 
[    6.834819] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[    6.835036] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[    6.835767] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Appears that device is present unable to power up?  Has anyone seen this issue and/or does anyone know what I should do to further troubleshoot this issue.  I followed a forum post instructions to download and install the device drivers from the Intel site (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html), but it didn't seem to have any impact on the issue.  IE didn't seem to help.  Thanks for any all information you guys can provide!

Comment: Did you happen to use Windows on this machine?

Comment: The machine originally had windows 10 loaded but I had a HDD failure. I purchased and replaced the faulty hard drive then loaded Ubuntu to after drive replacement.

Comment: Power down, remove power cord(and battery if possible), then hold the power key for 30 seconds, reconnect power cord/battery and boot

Comment: Same issue here on Fedora. What's annoying is that this device was working fine a couple of weeks ago.