WiFi networks don't show
My WiFi doesn't show any networks. I tried hot spotting from my phone, but it doesn't work.

WiFi card is the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic


You need to add some context. Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466979/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7265-wifi-adaptor-not-recognized-in-ubuntu-23-04 and see if you can add similar context to what is given.
